# htaccess - remove middle part of url from a &_GET

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have urls like this:

```
www.example.com/artworks/arte-1/english-name-1
```

I want to remove arte-1 and make the urls like this:

```
www.example.com/artworks/english-name-1
```

Both arte-1 and english-name-1 come from &_GET results. Sometimes they are the same, like

```
www.example.com/artworks/dimension/dimension
```

But I want to get the first and third parts of the url. And even if they are different, can't find a way to do it. One of the things I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^artworks/([a-z0-9-]+)/?([a-z0-9-]+)$ $1 [R=302,L]
```

And I also tried:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} artworks/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)
RewriteRule ^ artworks/$2? [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} artes/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)
RewriteRule ^ artes/%2? [L]
```

I placed them right after RewriteEngine On, but it doesn't work. My working htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^artworks\/([a-z0-9-]+)\/([a-z0-9-]+)\/?$ index.php?id=artworks&pintura=$1&versao=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^artes\/([a-z0-9-]+)\/([a-z0-9-]+)\/?$ index.php?id=artes&pintura=$1&versao=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)\/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Can i please get some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown attempts, please try following rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Newly added rules here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(artworks)/(?:[\w-]+)/([\w-]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(artworks)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&versao=$2 [NC,L]

##OP's already existing rules edited a bit for improvement here.
RewriteRule ^artworks/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?id=artworks&pintura=$1&versao=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^artes/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?id=artes&pintura=$1&versao=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: 1st - I hit, for example, example.com/artes/o-passaro/o-passaro or example.com/artworks/o-passaro/the-bird. They all come from $_GET but first strings (arte and artworks) are set for this case. 2nd - I need example.com/artes/o-passaro (first and third strings) and artworks/the-bird. Please don't be sorry. :) Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @ClaireR., yes we can do it. so you want it like: `index.php?id=artwork&versao=$2 [L]`? But not sure this is a guess :) you need to tell me in terms of url example like: `example.com/artworks/o-passaro/the-bird` should be served by `index.php?id=artwork&versao=the-bird [L]`? Like this, let me know in this form and I will get clear picture of it then, cheers.

Comment: Yes, that's it! However I had to put that 'pintura' there.

Comment: @ClaireR., ok let me try to ask again here(sorry if I am not clear here trying my best to help), for URL `example.com/artworks/o-passaro/the-bird` which parameters you want to pass to index.php and how? Eg: `id=artworks&versao=the-bird`? Like that if you can explain me I will understand it better IMHO.

Comment: I need example.com/artworks/the-bird - I want to pass id and versao. Sorry if I still didn't get it. :(

Comment: @ClaireR., its working fine for me, could you please confirm if your index.php is placed with .htaccess file? I mean like: `/root/htaccess` and `/root/index.php`?

Comment: Yes, they're in the same folder. Sorry for taking your time. ;(

Comment: @ClaireR., When I test url like: `curl -IL "http://localhost:80/artworks/o-passaro/the-bird"` in Linux box then it shows url like `http://localhost:80/artworks/the-bird`  which is giving me 200 OK results, which is getting served by index.php file in backend.

Comment: I'll keep trying as it's working for you. That's the answer, I just need to know what I'm doing wrong. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @ClaireR., may be its cache issue. Any other rules you have apart from these? NOT sure if they are effecting these then.

Comment: I'm on localhost too. Is there something that could be wrong here on my computer? I have no rules apart from those.

Comment: Thank you for your help, you were super. I'll keep trying. I'll upvote your answer. :)

Comment: @ClaireR., trust me code is working well for me in localhost linux. May be either its cache issue OR could be network issue. One more thing is your htaccess is enabled? I mean does any other rules working? Just double check it once, who knows if htaccess file is disabled :)

Comment: It's enabled, the other rules all work. But yes, I'll double check it. Thank you :)

Comment: @ClaireR., Your welcome, cheers and happy learning, trust me these rules are fine(when I check in my local), check other things, Keep asking Good questions on this great forum cheers.